# Почему findstr выводит всю строку, в которой найдено совпадение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, cmd

Например, у меня есть файл `regex.txt` с таким содержимым:

```
text
TEXT
text TEXT
```

И я пишу в cmd: `findstr "T" regex.txt`. По идее должно вывестись

```
T
T
```

Но выводится

```
TEXT
text TEXT
```

То есть выводиться вся строка, в которой найдено соответствие. А как сделать так, чтобы выводилось только соответствие?

Comment: `findstr` всегда выводит целую строку, у этой утилиты нет возможности вывода совпадений. Используйте PowerShell вместо findstr.

Comment: Спасибо большое!